# Trying to pass filename to ExcelWriter

Tags: python, pandas, time, xlsxwriter

I am trying to pass a customized filename variable to ExcelWriter but cannot get the ExcelWriter portion of this to work for some reason.  If I replace "Sheetname" with "Temp.xlsx" in the ExcelWriter function this works, but i'm not able to pass my variable to the function.  I need to be able to store today's date in the filename every time the script is run.

```
Spreadsheet = pandas.DataFrame()
Sheetname = 'Makino Machine Metrics ' + time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") +'.xlsx'
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(Sheetname, engine = 'xlsxwriter')
Spreadsheet.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= 'Results',index = False)
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Results']
writer.save()
```

Thanks in Advance for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I run your program I get the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
         'Makino Machine Metrics 07/12/2016.xlsx'
```

You can fix it by removing the forward slashes from the date part:

```
import pandas
import time

Spreadsheet = pandas.DataFrame()
Sheetname = 'Makino Machine Metrics ' + time.strftime("%m_%d_%Y") +'.xlsx'
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(Sheetname, engine = 'xlsxwriter')

Spreadsheet.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Results', index=False)
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Results']
writer.save()
```

Looks like the error comes from open:

```
 >>> open('12/12/12.xlsx', 'w')   
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '12/12/12.xlsx'
```

So, either escape those characters or use another character in the date, like in the example above.